# Authentication with CodeIgniter - Additional Session Information

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

I have been an avid reader of stackoverflow for a long period of time, and now its my turn to ask a question.

I followed http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/easy-authentication-with-codeigniter/ tutorial and have managed to get it to work flawlessly for my self, however I need to expand the system ever so slightly. I need to be able to after the user has been verified to pull additional row fields of the authenticated person and store in session variables, for use in other controllers for sending information back to the database.

For instance I want to have in a sessional variable $f_name, and I need their $username. 
I have looked high and low and have found answers but they have only confused me.

My Model:

```
class admin_model extends CI_Model {
 function __construct( )
 {

 }

 public function verify_user($user_id, $password)
 {
 $q = $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id)
 ->where('password', sha1($password))->limit(1)->get('users');

 if ( $q->num_rows > 0   ){
     return $q->row();
 }
return false;

}

}
```

My Controller:

```
class admin extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
parent:: __construct();
session_start();


}

public function index()
{
    if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        redirect('welcome');
    }
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_id', 'User ID', 'required|min_length[8]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() !==false){
       $this->load->model('admin_model');
      $res = $this
          ->admin_model
          ->verify_user(
          $this->input->post('user_id'),
          $this->input->post('password')
      );
   if ($res !== false) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $this->input->post('user_id');
    redirect ('welcome');
   }






    }

    $this->load->view('login_view');
}

public function logout(){

    session_destroy();
    redirect ('admin');
}
}
```

Thanks again guys and I look forward to your answers\suggestions

Comment: why don't you use CI's database sessions? That way you can query that table for for relevant data.

Comment: Is it possible that I could get an example of how to implement what I need with the CI's database sessions? Im still new to CI

Comment: You don't need anything, just set a config parameter. All the queries are handled automatically when you fetch a session element ($this->session->userdata('element'))

Comment: I don't quite understand could you please provide more detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things: 
- the `__construct()` function in `admin_model` needs `parent::__construct` (or the function could be removed since it's empty) to inherit the code igniter model constructor. 
- code igniter and PHP sessions are different. You're using PHP sessions, which means that you'll have to call `session_start()` before any output is sent on every page in which you'd like to access the session data. This can also be set for every page in your php.ini by turning on session.autostart

If you'd like to use code igniter sessions, look here:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

### UPDATE 12/21/2012

Try setting the session variables from the database row returned:

`$_SESSION['f_name'] = $res->f_name;` and `$_SESSION['username'] = $res->username;` in the same place as where you're setting the session user id variable. I'm assuming your database fields are mapping to the fields that you're wanting to use for the f_name and username fields.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think the parent::_construct was a typo on my behalf.

I'm still not 100% convinced on how I can get the original information from the database row into the session.

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question

Comment: Try setting the session variables from the database row returned:
$_SESSION['f_name'] = $res->f_name; and $_SESSION['username'] = $res->username; in the same place as where you're setting the session user id variable. I'm assuming your database fields are mapping to the fields that you're wanting to use for the f_name and username fields.

Comment: @KenPloeger if you edit your actual answer I can remove my downvote :)

Comment: @KenPloeger your last post worked like a charm. original reply has been marked as the answer. a side note, I read the link about CI sessions and I have a simple question about setting it up $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE; sets the database, $f_name = $this->session->userdata('f_name'); makes it usable, what is the code to get it to store like $_SESSION['f_name'] = $res->f_name;

Comment: @RohanPeters Is there a reason in your app for using the code igniter database session storage? There's likely going to be some setup involved...I believe the code would be something along the lines of $this->session->userdata('f_name'); (which would be how you'd store it for code igniter cookie session storage as well). If you're still wondering what to do with the other options for sessions, I'd suggest opening another question.